# Ads should be hidden when questions are printed

Tags: feature-request, printing

I wanted to print out a question on SO and had to waste some ink on printing the ad. I think that the ads should be hidden by default in the print stylesheet. This is normal practice on many sites.

[image with pink arrow http://img.skitch.com/20100502-gyyp2jfbjdxe3kf5isms2hjm76.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100502-gyyp2jfbjdxe3kf5isms2hjm76.jpg)

Comment: I agree. Some people might say that this should only be available for users that have more than 200 rep (AFAIK that's how much you need to have less advertising appear on each page), but I don't think so.

Comment: There's a stylesheet for printing?

Comment: @Ether, no, but the CSS includes `@media print` directives. (Don't be fooled by Firebug; [it won't show the directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765349/how-to-see-the-print-media-css-in-firebug/2754264#2754264) but instead might just show you CSS that is not always active...)

Comment: And the "Browse other questions tagged ..." section and "add comment" should also be removed.  The single question I have printed would probably only be 1 page if all of these were done.

Comment: You might be interested in [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/)

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround: [The Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) might help.

(Beware: self-updating bookmarklet. Know who you trust.)

Comment: Hmmm, it seems this did not get a downvote, but a flag? May I ask why?

Comment: I could see how someone might think this is adspam for a non-free product.

Comment: Ai, non-free? I've always used it as free. Let me check again... Update: nope, still free. Let me add "bookmarklet" then. Oh, I already did. Confused! ;-)

Comment: How could anybody who actually looked at the linked page think this is ad spam?